# Email addresses display as [email protected] in entries

Tags: channel-entries, email, entries, author

I am using EE v3.4.3.

In the 'options' tab of entries, the 'author' field displays the list of members. Until recently they showed correctly, but for some reason, they now display like:

[email protected]
[email protected]
[email protected]
[email protected]
...

[image]

Does anyone know why this is, and how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the domain is being routed through CloudFlare, and their [email obsfucation feature](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-) has been enabled.